HLS streaming won't play on website using nginx, rtmp with OBS
I setup a NGNIX server with RTMP using OBS on Windows 10. I have OBS sending the files to the NGNIX folder (temp/hls). If I use VLC with RTMP it works and I can see the stream in VLC just fine. I setup a simple webpage to display the video. It does not work. I added a public URL to make sure that my web page code is correct. It plays just fine. I read everything I could find but I am at a loss as to why it won't play on my website.
I opened port 8181 on my windows firewall and router. I provided the RTMP stat info which shows the file test is streaming. My thoughts are either a port issue or error in the config file or URL issue. Thanks for any help.
Here is the HTML/JS code for the website:
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Live Streaming</title>
    <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.11/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.14.1/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
   
        <div>
            <video muted autoplay id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup='{"fluid": true}' controls preload="none">
                <!--source  src="https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL"-->
                <source src="https://127.0.0.1:8181/hls/test.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" >                   
            </video>
        </div>
        
    <script>
        var player = videojs('#player');
        player.play();
    </script>


</body>

Here is the NGINX config:
    #user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/rtmp_error.log debug;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 8192;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            meta copy;
            
        }

        application hls {
            live on;            
            hls on;  
            hls_path temp/hls;  
            hls_fragment 8s;  
            
        }
    }
}

http {
    server {
        listen      8181;
        
        location / {
            root html;
        }
        
        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        }

        location /stat.xsl {
            root html;
        }
        
        location /hls {  
            #server hls fragments  
            types{  
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;  
                video/mp2t ts;  
            }  
            alias temp/hls;  
            expires -1;  
        }  
    }
}

Here is the RTMP stat
RTMP stat information

Where are you testing it from? Form the same Windows 10 system that nginx is running on, or from a different system? Your HTML video source URL is using the loopback address 127.0.0.1, so it's telling the client device to ask request the stream from the client device, not the server. Replace that loopback address with an address for the server that the client devices can reach.

They are both on the same physical machine. I am using xampp for my web server. I always start my testing on the same machine to rule out network issues as a cause of a problem.
